# dockerize a CLI that prompts for password

Tags: docker, stdout, tty

Struggling to get a docker app to both pipe output to a file, and read input. Running the same command in bash works fine.

The command is a CLI I created called [envwarden](https://github.com/envwarden/envwarden) (a simple bash script wrapping around the [Bitwarden CLI](https://github.com/bitwarden/cli)).

Easiest to show an example:

### locally

Running it locally (not inside docker), it works as expected:

```
$ ./envwarden --dotenv >/tmp/secrets.txt
.envwarden file not found in /home/user ... prompting for credentials
? Email address: my@email.addr
? Master password: [hidden]
```

The prompts work fine. I can type in my email (shown), password (hidden), and the output goes to `/tmp/secrets.txt` just fine.

### with docker

With docker, things behave a bit differently.

With `docker run -ti` (or just `docker run -t`), there's no prompt at all for email or password...

```
$ docker run --rm -ti envwarden/envwarden envwarden --dotenv >/tmp/secrets.txt

# ... no output ...
```

With `docker run -i`, the prompt shows, but anything I type is repeated, and password is shown as well! :-/

```
$ docker run --rm -i envwarden/envwarden envwarden --dotenv >/tmp/secrets.txt
.envwarden file not found in /root ... prompting for credentials
? Email address: my@email.address
? Email address: my@email.address
? Master password: [input is hidden] my password
? Master password: [hidden]
```

`docker run`, without `-t` or `-i` it shows the prompt, but fails to get input

```
$ docker run --rm envwarden/envwarden envwarden --dotenv >/tmp/secrets.txt
.envwarden file not found in /root ... prompting for credentials
? Email address: unable to login or sync with bitwarden.
```

### Further details

Here's the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/envwarden/envwarden/blob/master/Dockerfile) and [docker-entrypoint.sh](https://github.com/envwarden/envwarden/blob/master/docker-entrypoint.sh)

### Question

How can I get docker to match the same behaviour as running locally? i.e. prompt for password without showing it, and redirect output to stdout.

Comment: what is in `docker-entrypoint.sh`?

Comment: [docker-entrypoint.sh](https://github.com/envwarden/envwarden/blob/master/docker-entrypoint.sh) (sorry, forgot to link to it, it's all part of the repo. Edited my question to include it as well)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior you observe is due to the way `docker run` handles standard streams.

In particular, this is related to [moby/moby#725](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/725) and PR [moby/moby#741](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/741):

- If you pass no `-i` nor `-t` flag to `docker run`: your terminal is not attached to the standard input of your main program, which thereby behaves as if you had typed empty strings as credentials.
- If you only pass the `-i` flag to `docker run`, your terminal is attached to your program's stdin, but no pseudo-TTY is allocated, implying you get a not very user-friendly CLI interaction (no hiding feature during password typing, and possible duplication of output lines).
- If you pass the `-it` flags to `docker run`: a pseudo-TTY is allocated, so the password prompt should work (hiding what you type), but at the same time, **the stdout and stderr streams are mixed**, so when you append the `>/tmp/secrets.txt` redirection, you don't actually see the prompt as everything is sent to your `/tmp/secrets.txt` file!

All in all, to achieve what you want I guess you should stick to the `-it` option, but rather use a bash redirection "inside" the container (not outside) and also rely on some bind-mount option.

Hence the following proof of concept:

```
export out="/tmp/secrets.txt"  # absolute path to the output file in the host
docker run --rm -it -v "$out:$out" envwarden/envwarden \
  /bin/bash -c "envwarden --dotenv >$out"
cat "$out"
```

(This should work normally, but I did not try it on your particular instance, so comments are welcome.)

Comment: Thanks! I'm still a bit confused about the issues you linked to, and why can't docker split output to stdout and stderr, but I understand the workaround. Not that pretty unfortunately, because it doesn't let you use the docker version as a drop-in replacement, but at least it's something :)

Comment: @gingerlime I think this issue (the fact stderr and stdout are entangled when using `-it`) is not specific to Docker as a similar issue arises with `ssh` for exemple: [stderr over ssh -t](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/134139/297058). So either you rely on the workaround I suggested (which indeed won't compose well with bash aliases or so), or you drop the `-t` option and do what you had tried in the first place, `docker run --rm -i envwarden/envwarden envwarden --dotenv >/tmp/secrets.txt` (and just lose the TTY-based password hiding feature).

Comment: Thanks again, Erik. The password hiding thing is quite crucial I would say in this case... But I'm happy to at least have a workaround... It didn't occur to me, but makes perfect sense once you mentioned it :) ... I thought docker runs in a local process, so it should be able to split stderr, stdout, but obviously if it were so simple they'd do it already. So I'm obviously underestimating the complexity. It does hinder however docker being used as a simple way to package apps I suppose.